# calculating duration (Date - Date) from a case Expression

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, casting

I'm writing a complex query and I'm having some problems with calculating from case ***expression*** (*thank you*). Essentially, thanks to some great help on this site I managed to solve another issue by using an ordered table but now one of the select statements I was previously using no longer functions with the OT.

I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

The core of the problem is that I want to calculate duration from subtracting a start date from an end date. The code I had previously used was

```
select
    cast((CASE 
             WHEN ap.startLIKE '%[^0-9]%' 
                THEN CAST(ap.end as datetime) 
                ELSE NULL 
          END)
          -
          (CASE 
              WHEN ap.start LIKE '%[^0-9]%' 
                 THEN CAST(ap.start as datetime) 
                 ELSE NULL 
           END) as time) as Duration, 
    ap.start, ap.end, ap.description
from 
    Table as AP
group by 
    ap.start, ap.end, ap.description
```

but when I changed to draw this information from the ordered table as:

```
Select 
    ot.starttime as "Start Time", 
    ot.endtime as "End Time", 
    ot.description "Description", 
    ot.entrynumber as "ID Number",
    cast((CASE 
             WHEN ot.endtime LIKE '%[^0-9]%' 
                THEN CAST(ot.endtime as datetime) 
             ELSE NULL 
          END)
          -
          (CASE 
              WHEN ot.starttime LIKE '%[^0-9]%' 
                 THEN CAST(ot.starttime as datetime) 
              ELSE NULL 
           END) as time) as duration
From
    OrderedTable as OT
group by
    ot.starttime, ot.endtime, ot.description, ot.entrynumber
order by 
    ot.endtime
```

I get the error. Previously applying the group by clause had removed the error, but not from the ordered table.

Genuinely unsure what is causing the problem as I've been trying to eliminate the conversion to date issue constantly, I would appreciate any help.

The originating problem has been that the date fields on the server are in nvarchar format and not datetime, I've been trying to get around that.

Comment: Case expression, not case statement.

Comment: Clearly, `OrderedTable` has rows with different date formats that are failing the conversion.

Comment: The source Data is the same however, ap.starttime = ot.starttime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the column was formatted in nvarchar32 rather than date/time which it should have been, it resulted in periodically the database receiving a text value for (some) open records for the finish time rather than a NULL value. 
This occurred only periodically and for whatever reason proposed by whoever designed the database.

This ideally shouldn't happen since its against database convention to do this kind of thing, as NULL values are simply ignored by calculation functions since they are unknown. Still unclear why the case expression didn't resolve the issue, but using the filter FinishTime <> "error text", I resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly - you can use

`TIMEDIFF(date1, date2)` 
or `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, date2, date1);`

where date2 < date1 to find the time between two dates. In the first case you will get the result in HH:mm:ss format and in the second case it will be in seconds - depends what you need. Since you didn't post an example how a date looks in your column I can't be sure, but I think you wont need conversions - you can substract your dates as chars (If they look this way '2016-12-31 11:02:00')

Comment: I've attempted to subtract them directly

Comment: the reason for the case expression is that it is attempting to remove erroneous data that is not in date format since the column is in nvchar format rather than date/time. 
The thing is that it works when its applied to the table proper but not the Ordered Table created in the query, or when placed inside the OT clause. I'm just trying to get to the bottom of the issue as I'm dealing with 90+ thousand rows and I can't easily see what's causing the problem.

Comment: I understand. Can you tell me why you check starttime twice (in each case)? Because here `CASE 
             WHEN ot.starttime LIKE '%[^0-9]%' 
                THEN CAST(ot.endtime as datetime) 
             ELSE NULL 
          END` you check starttime and then convert endtime

Comment: Can you provide some example data from the 2 columns which you want to subtract?

Comment: The starttime twice issue was a typo on my part (sorry). I'm not sure I could provide the data I'm using though it is in timestamp format (DD/MM/YYY HH:MM:SS) as my employer is probably pretty paranoid about that kind of thing and if its one or two entries causing problems it would take sifting through 90,000 rows to do it, at the moment its sitting in a much bigger query which is returning no rows with the same error.

I did try the TIMEDIFF function instead as you suggested with some initial success, but now I'm incurring the same problem.